# How to uninstall Ubuntu without removing or uninstalling Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, uninstall

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and Windows 7 on the same computer.  I want to uninstall Ubuntu and just use Windows 7.  I'm afraid if I uninstall Ubuntu, it will remove Windows 7 as well.

How can I uninstall Ubuntu without affecting Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution is to insert at boot your USB stick (or CD) with Windows on it and make a `"repair startup"`, this way, grub will be substituted by the windows boot, then use a tool like [`Gparted`](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) or [`Partition wizard`](http://www.partitionwizard.com/) to delete all linux partitions.

That should do it. Hope it helps.

```
Remember Always to have a decent Backup!!
```

Also you could even delete your linux partitions using the windows partitions management

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it. Don't have to go messing around with GRUB.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your using GRUB to boot into Windows as well, in which case you will need to make sure you have a Windows CD/DVD on hand. As long as Windows is the first installation(this is the most common) you should have no issues.

First off any activity such as this is risky, make sure you have a [good backup](http://data-backup-software-review.toptenreviews.com/why-backup-your-computer.html) even if you do everything properly a chance of an issue could arise!

When in Windows right click on Computer and click on manage. You should then go to Disk Management. You will see an Unknown partition type, you can delete and format this. THIS WILL REMOVE ALL LINUX DATA!!!!

Now you have also killed your boot loader so you will need to repair it.

Instructions can be found at [this howtogeek.com page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/).